# how can i know which is the day that corresponds to the first day of a month in a specific date?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a date like "11/01/2015" and I want to know the first day for month 11?

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
DateTime  endDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddDays(30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

I thought about that but I don't know how to retrieve the day in French!!

thanks

Comment: Do you want to know if the first day is a Monday or Tuesday or Wednesday etc.?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking here. What has the language to do with anything?

Comment: The first day of every month is always 1. Please explain better your question

Comment: i want to know if the first day of the month is a Monday or Tuesday.....etc!!!

Comment: I want to know if the first day is a Monday or Tuesday or Wednesday etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `DayOfWeek` property on a `DateTime` instance constructed with the year/month of the input date:

```
var time = DateTime.Parse("11/01/2015");
var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(time.Year, time.Month, 1);
Console.WriteLine(firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek);
```

To get the day in French use the `CultureInfo` of the language you are interested in :

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Console.WriteLine(culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek));
```

Output:

> Sunday
>
> dimanche